# JSON schema to check if only one of the array items contains a property

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Is there a way to check whether a property is present in the array, but only in one of the items?

In the following example, the "filename" and "format" must be present at least in one and only in one array item.

Valid JSON examples:

```json
{
    "myarray": [
        {
            "name": "Example 1"
        },
        {
            "filename": "example.txt",
            "format": "txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
{
    "myarray": [
        {
            "name": "Example 2"
            "filename": "example.txt"
        },
        {
            "format": "txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

Invalid JSON example:

```json
{
    "myarray": [
        {
            "name": "Example 3"
            "filename": "example.txt"
            "format": "txt"
        },
        {
            "filename": "example3.txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

I was able to reach this by the following schema, but it works for one property only. When I add format, it does not work either for "filename" or for "format".

```json
"myarray": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "filename": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "contains": {
        "required": [
            "filename"
        ]
    },
    "not": {
        "items": {
            "required": [
                "filename"
            ],
            "minProperties": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `allOf` since you need to match multiple and `minContains` and `maxContains` since you have a at least one and only one condition.

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "myarray": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "filename": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "format": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "allOf": [
        {
          "contains": {
            "required": [
              "filename"
            ]
          },
          "minContains": 1,
          "maxContains": 1
        },
        {
          "contains": {
            "required": [
              "format"
            ]
          },
          "minContains": 1,
          "maxContains": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. If I remove the filename from all items it passes.

Comment: This will work from Draft 2019-09 where `minContains` and `maxContains` are supported. You can verify this at https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/. If you have a constraint on which specification version you can use you should state that in your question.

Comment: The following shows that if filename is removed there is an error. https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/wpLVElXC